# Requires on setter/getter in vala

Tags: vala, design-by-contract

Is there any way to do something like the following in Vala ?

```
public int year {
    get { return this.year; }
    set requires (1500 < value && value < 2050) { this.year = value; }
}
```

Comment: technically it should be possible, but I don't know if the syntax allows it yet. What I'd do as a workaround is to define a private setter function with the contract, and call that in the public setter.

Comment: It's a shame if syntax doesn't allows it. Even if your workaround is clean, it is still a workaround. Hope they add the syntax someday

Comment: Well, you can always open a feature request on their bugtracker, or even try to implement it yourself and send some patches =) Vala is still in development.

Comment: Ticket in bugtracker it is : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but 'requires' is really just syntactic sugar for [GLib.return_if_fail](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.return_if_fail.html) and [GLib.return_val_if_fail](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.return_val_if_fail.html), so you could just do:

```
public int year {
    get { return this.year; }
    set {
        GLib.return_if_fail (1500 < value && value < 2050);
        this.year = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is good to know! Disappointing however as syntax looks cleaner with 'requires'. Where did you find the information about requires being an alias for GLib.return_if_fail ? Valadoc from those 2 links to GLib.return_if_fail and GLib.return_va_if_fail are not so verbose.

Comment: I don't know that it's documented anywhere, I'm just very familiar with how valac translates between Vala and C.  I agree that the syntax support looks nicer... if you have time, it would be great if you file a feature request on Vala's bug tracker (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=vala).